# Can game mods create buffer overflow vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, secure-coding

I don't usually post in forums because normally I can find any answer I need using Google. However every search that I am running is giving me very specific results, such as buffer overflow vulnerabilities that already exist for a specific game or system which is not what I need.

I have a home network including Windows Server 2008 R2 and my son wants to start a Minecraft server which of course I want to give him full access to so he can learn. However, I know that every game is "moddable" and he uses custom maps and the like in a lot of his games.

My concern is that I am going to create security risks on my network based on inexperienced programming. Will giving him the ability to install and create mods on my server potentially open up vulnerabilities (outside of the open Minecraft ports) due to the possible inexperience of people actually writing the mods? Or do mods just simply not work that way and I can't find  an answer to my question because it's retarded and no one actually programs a mod lol?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about securing a server, not programming.

Comment: I know how to secure my server. My question is about programming mods because I don't know how that is done. I am wondering if there are potential risks from whoever is coding the mod.

Comment: It's possible this question would be better asked on security.stackexchange.com. Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the way the mod system works for the game, and whether the game itself is sandboxed. Importantly, no software is perfectly secure. You have to decide what level of security and reliability you are happy with.

There are several ways a mod could expose a vulnerability:

1. The game could allow the mod access to an inappropriately permissive set of actions, such as access to the filesystem. This can include the developer not sandboxing the mod properly.
2. The mod could exploit a vulnerability in the game's API to access actions the game developer didn't intend. This would be due to a bug in the API.
3. The mod could exploit a vulnerability in the language engine (for example, Java has a long history of security vulnerabilities).
4. The mod itself could be vulnerable to attack, and could be made to launch one of the attacks above.

If the mod system is script or VM based, such as Lua, JavaScript or Java, I would feel *relatively* safe installing mods (so long as the game has a well implemented API/sandbox), because exploits 2-4 are relatively unlikely.

(My understanding of *native* code mods/plugins is limited, but I'm pretty sure you MUST trust a native mod if you want to run it. Even if you do, it might still be exploitable. )

My understanding of minecraft mods is that they are written in java. My feeling about the Mojang guys is that they know what they're doing, so I'd be surprised if their mod API isn't exceptionally well designed and implemented. Having said that, installing mods *necessarily* introduces a security risk.

If this risk is unacceptable, you can reduce it by introducing depth to the system. Why not, say, run your minecraft server in a virtual machine, with limited access to the network (only required ports, for example)? That way the impact of  vulnerabilities is reduced greatly.

I'd recommend creating a Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox (because they're both free as in beer), but you could install it on whatever OS you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both responses were helpful and I really appreciate you guys taking the time to answer. This is exactly the type of information I was looking for aaaidan. I had already decided to accept the risk of running a Minecraft server because I trust that they are at least putting in some effort to provide secure code. I just wasn't sure about mods that get placed in later, but you have helped me understand how they interact and this really helps me be able to measure my risk because now I can research individual topics.

Comment: Glad we've helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overrun vulnerabilities are associated with programming languages that permit unchecked memory access. Minecraft is written in Java, a language which is not susceptible to buffer overruns, so a pure-Java mod would be very unlikely to exhibit anything resembling this kind of vulnerability.

Naturally programs in Java can still be vulnerable to other kinds of security issue, either against the game itself (eg there have been game-account login exploits against Minecraft servers) or against the server (I'm not aware of any known cases of this for Minecraft, but it's always possible). The usual mitigations for running servers apply, for example lock down network access to good IPs if possible, run server as limited user and so on.